# PyQGIS generate WMS service description XML for TMS service

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, wms, xyz, tile-map-service

I am currently writing a QGIS Plugin, for which i require a WMS service description XML file for the currently selected layer (as long as it is a XYZ layer), like [this](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml) one for OSM.

At least i think I need such a file, because I have not found a way to pass a url to gdalinfo directly. When I pass an url like `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png` to gdalinfo, I get an HTTP 403 as return. If there is a way, please let me know.

How do I generate such a file from an XYZ layer in QGIS?

I found [this](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html#generation-of-wms-service-description-xml-file), but when trying
`gdal_translate https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png target.xml -of WMS` it also returns a 403 error code.

Comment: @nmtoken did you mean to write more? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tile service supports the TMS specification http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification
it is possible to read first the service metadata
gdalinfo http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0
and select one of the subdatasets in the service and use that with gdal_translate for creating the XML configuration file.

gdal_translate -of WMS "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Apoi@EPSG%3A900913@png" wmstest.xml

The wmstest.xml file:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
    <ServerUrl>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/tiger%3Apoi@EPSG%3A900913@png/${z}/${x}/${y}.${format}</ServerUrl>
    <Format>png</Format>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-8296780.79703125</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>5009377.085000001</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>-8218509.280078124</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>4931105.568046875</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>30</TileLevel>
    <SizeX>536870912</SizeX>
    <SizeY>536870912</SizeY>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:900913</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the OSM tile usage policies from https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

What you hit here is this requirement:

> **Technical Usage Requirements**
>
> Valid HTTP User-Agent identifying application. Faking another app’s
> User-Agent WILL get you blocked.

The way to set User-Agent for GDAL is documented in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_HTTP_USERAGENT
and you can test that it works at least as long as other tile usage policies will block you

```
gdalinfo https://tile.openstreetmap.org/5/20/13.png --config GDAL_HTTP_USERAGENT "GDAL WMS driver (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html)"


Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: none associated
Size is 256, 256
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
...
```

Hint: by setting another config option the GDAL utilities print lots of information about network services that are used through curl:

```
--config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES
```

When it comes to  a TMS minidriver example https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml there is this commented section about UserAgent:

```
<UserAgent>Please add a specific user agent text, to avoid the default one being used, and potentially blocked by OSM servers in case a too big usage of it would be seen</UserAgent>
```

Did you edit and un-comment that as suggested?

Comment: I edited the UserAgent in the xml, but with a xml it worked even before. My question is, how can I generate such an xml file from only data which can be read from a qgis layer (such as url, CRS and some more infos).

Comment: I do not know what QGIS can do, but if the tile service follows the TMS specification then you can use the workflow that I wrote as another answer. But many tile services do not advertise any standardized metadata and the best option is probably to use the GDAL examples as a template as you did.

Comment: Well, something like osm follows TMS spec, right? Otherwise, [this](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml) wouldnt work. But I cant find the url endpoint for OSM to generate the XML with gdal translate (like in your other answer). Is there simply no unform url? The only thing I can extract from QGIS is `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. Which on itself is not even an url, x,y and z obv. need to be replaced.

Comment: OSM services do not follow the TMS specification when it comes to service metadata, see  https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification#Root_Resource. The URL or tile access template is not enough for clients to recognize all features of the service automatically. For example, what is the coordinate system. A human user can read service documentation and guess all that what is not documented and write the parameters manually.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to generate such  a file when just an URL is given (in this case)?

Comment: Not with existing GDAL tools. Certainly doable with some scripting language or even with a text editor that supports macros if it is enough to take some GDAL example as a template and just change the server URL part.